# How do I set a glitched text on a sing in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So now I know how to send a gliched text using the /tellraw command, and I also wanted to use that text on sings. So i searched it up and i found a command,( /setblock ~ ~ ~ standing_sign 0 replace {Text1:"{"text":"This text will not be seen",obfuscated:"true"}"} ) but, it didn't work, it said that this is a incorrect command.  also I tried normal sings and typing first  §k  and it did show on the sing it's "glitchy" but when i closed the sing, there were just scrambled letters, and that's it. I don't know if the command works on earlier versions, because i was on my multiplayer server i created on 1.16.5 and i had operator here.

Comment: Where did you find this command? Please share.

Answer (score 1):

You have used both the wrong name and Syntax in your command, this would be your desired command:

```
/setblock [x] [y] [z] oak_sign[rotation=0]{Text1:"{\"text\":\"This text will not be seen\",\"obfuscated\":true}"}
```

Remember to change `rotation` to change where the sign is facing.

You could also use the `data` command to change what a sign says:

```
/data merge block [x] [y] [z] {Text1:"{\"text\":\"This text will not be seen\",\"obfuscated\":true}"}
```

Comment: You can also use single quote notation to avoid escaping those double quotes: `{Text1:'{"text":"Test"}'}`